# SQL Server Stored Procedure Multiple Condtions

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, t-sql

I have this LINQ in C#, which I have to convert to a SQL query. And I am not sure how to do multiple filtering based on conditions:

```
var geofenceReport = companyContext.GeofenceSimpleReports.Where(x => x.EnterTime != null && x.ExitTime != null && x.MinutesInGeofence != null).AsQueryable();

if (model.GeofenceId != -1)
{
    geofenceReport = geofenceReport.Where(x => x.iGeofenceId == model.GeofenceId).AsQueryable();
}

if (model.AssetId != -1)
{
    geofenceReport = geofenceReport.Where(x => x.iAssetId == model.AssetId).AsQueryable();
}

if (model.CategoryId != -1)
{
    geofenceReport = geofenceReport.Where(x => x.iCategoryId == model.CategoryId).AsQueryable();
}

if (model.SiteId != -1)
{
    geofenceReport = geofenceReport.Where(x => x.iSiteId == model.SiteId).AsQueryable();
}

geofenceReport = geofenceReport
                   .Where(x => x.EnterTime >= model.StartDateTime && 
                          x.EnterTime <= model.EndDateTime) 
                   .AsQueryable();
```

So this is what I came up with in SQL:

I created a new type for `AssetId`:

```
USE myDatabase
GO

CREATE TYPE idTable AS TABLE (id INT)
```

And then in SQL:

```
USE myDatabase
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[xPT_GetGeofenceSummaryReport]
    @iAssetIds idTable,
    @iGeofenceId INT,
    @iCategoryId INT,
    @iSiteId INT,
    @iAssetId INT
AS

IF @iAssetId != -1
    SELECT * FROM GeofenceSimpleReport WHERE iAssetId in (@iAssetIds)

IF @iGeofenceId != -1
    SELECT * FROM GeofenceSimpleReport where iGeofenceId = @iGeofenceId

IF @iCategoryId != -1
    SELECT * FROM GeofenceSimpleReport where iCategoryId = @iCategoryId

IF @iSiteId != -1
    SELECT * FROM GeofenceSimpleReport where iSiteId = @iSiteId
```

and this `GeofenceSimpleReport` is a database view.

But this will not work as it is logically wrong. This will 4 separate selects from the `GeofenceSimpleReport`.

I need to have one read from `GeofenceSimpleReport` with all filters applied.

And I don't want to read this data temporarily into a TABLE/LIST in memory as there is a lot of data.

Is there a way to write this query dynamically like I am doing in LINQ?

Comment: Why not just use LINQ? What you had looked good, as long as your query fields are supposed to narrow down the result set (e.g., 'color = red' AND 'clothingType = sock').

Comment: Because this is a Report bringing back lots of data. and is causing SQL Timeout.... :-(

Comment: Depending on how much data, you could try indexing on the different fields.  How many rows are you bringing back?

Comment: ' GeofenceSimpleReport ' is a Database View and it is joining 5 tables. Then i have to apply filter on the View.

Comment: You can still index the view and the underlying tables.

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking about this procedurally, and going through a series of if-statements, rather than approaching your view as a set of data that you can filter all at once.

You can filter on the original criteria related to EntryTime, ExitTime, etc., and then for each parameter for which you provide a filterable value (not -1) then make sure the Id matches that record in the table.  Anything where you gave a -1 for the value will automatically make that `AND` statement true.

I do this sort of thing all the time by passing in nullable parameters - if they're non-`NULL` then I filter on them - otherwise they just evaluate to `true` and pass through.

```
USE myDatabase
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[xPT_GetGeofenceSummaryReport]
    @iAssetIds idTable,
    @iGeofenceId INT,
    @iCategoryId INT,
    @iSiteId INT,
    @iAssetId INT
AS
SELECT * 
   FROM GeofenceSimpleReport
   WHERE EnterTime IS NOT NULL 
   AND ExitTime IS NOT NULL
   AND MinutesInGeofence IS NOT NULL
   AND (@iAssetId = -1 OR iAssetId IN (@iAssetIds))
   AND (@iGeofenceId = -1 OR iGeofenceId = @iGeofenceId)
   AND (@iCategoryId = -1 OR iCategoryId = @ICategoryId)
   AND (@iSiteId = -1 OR iSiteId = @iSiteId)
```